# Flutter app not receiving message from Android through MethodChannel

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem**

I have an Android app that I am developing using mainly Flutter that is dependent on a .jar file being ran in the background. In main.dart there are 2 MethodChannel objects, one for sending commands to Java and one for receiving messages from Java. My flutter channel handling methods from Java is written as such:

```
_ui_channel.setMethodCallHandler(uiHandler);

Future<void> uiHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method){
      case "INPUT_ACCOUNT":
        print("Success!");
        break;
      default:
        print("This was called by " + call.method);
        break;
    }
  }
```

and in the Java side

```
MethodChannel out_channel= new MethodChannel(Objects.requireNonNull(getFlutterEngine()).getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), OUT_CHANNEL);

private void inputAccount(MethodChannel out_channel) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            out_channel.invokeMethod("INPUT_ACCOUNT", "", new MethodChannel.Result() {
                @Override
                public void success(Object result) {
                }

                @Override
                public void error(String errorCode, String errorMessage, Object errorDetails) {
                    Log.e("input", errorCode + "\n" + errorMessage);
                }

                @Override
                public void notImplemented() {
                }
            });
        });
```

I have verified that the Java code gets to the invokeMethod() call and that the channels are the same between the 2 sides. From what I've read online, this should be correct but Dart never receives the "INPUT_ACCOUNT" message and prints the "Success" message I've posted. Is there maybe something I'm missing in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: add some `Log.d` in `success` and `notImplemented` - what are on logs?

Comment: When I place logs there they do not get ran. When using a debugger and stepping through the code, they are never reached.

Comment: and if you add `Log.d` before and after `out_channel.invokeMethod` then you see only the first log?

Comment: Yes, I have ```Log.d``` statements around the entire block and they are being read.

Comment: you see both logs? before and after calling `out_channel.invokeMethod`? and the `MethodChannel.Result` does not call any `success` `error` or `notImplemented`? what if you use fake channel name?

Comment: Correct. Both logs are ran.

Comment: what if you use fake channel name? is `notImplemented` called? or `error`?

Comment: The flow of this is the Java Activity is created after a Broadcast is called xxx.com.action.INPUT_ACCOUNT and then it sends a message through the MethodChannel to run Dart Code, but the message is not received at the .dart file. The channel name being different would still have the inputAccount() method still be ran just sent on a different channel.

Comment: ```notImplemented``` and ```error``` are not called. Nothing within that lambda function is.

Comment: so you have some severe error - i would expect that `notImplemented` should be called at least - tried to uninstall the apk completly and install it again from the scratch?

Comment: No luck on a complete reinstall.

Comment: hmmmm, so get some beer or two - in 15 minutes the opening match of euro 2021 starts - italy vs turkey ;-)

Comment: I would love to but I'm at work lol. Enjoy the match!

Comment: good luck too ;-)